# Adding code hinting to a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, wysiwyg

If one would like to add code suggestion, or in-context auto completion (eg in an IDE or adding tags in SO), to a custom javascript wysiwyg, what might one do? I'm not even sure where to start Googling this. My original thoughts would be adding some absolute positioned unordered (or ordered) list pulling from a JSON, or something like that. I just figured some of you folks have probably mastered this type of project and could point me in the right direction.

I'm a long ways off from creating this, so it really is just a mental exercise for now, but it's bothered me for a while. Rather than looking for a jQuery plugin or CKEditor extention to do the job, I'm really just interested in the how. How is the "tooltip" displayed/selected/triggered? And, am I on the right track thinking JSON would be a good way to store the hints?